# (Python) How do I make imported functions automatically interact with global variables?

Tags: python, import, global-variables, python-import, currying

Let's say I want to imitate the following behaviour:

```py
Databases = ... # 'global' object

def fn(query):
    return query_database(query, Databases)
```

In this case Databases is a defined object so I can call it within my function.

Now suppose instead my function 'fn' and 'Databases' are in different files, and I import 'fn' into my Databases file. Can I make it so that it replicates a similar behaviour 'out-of-the-box'? My attempt so far is the following:

```py
def fn(query, databases = None):
    # databases are in a different file
    return query_database(query, databases)
```

```py
from fn_module import fn
from toolz import curry # alternatively import partial from functools, but it gives some issues

fn = curry(fn)(databases=Databases) # Now function works as expected
```

Now, this works, however, I have a lot of functions, and doing this is very tedious for every function since I have to curry a lot of different variables. Is there a more systematic approach to this (or simply a total overhaul)?

Comment: Functions use the globals of the module they're defined in (each module has its own globals). It's possible to change that but it's a bit of advanced hackery that is not really suited for production code. You'll have an easier time if you do it the other way 'round: import `Databases` into your `fn` module, then it's part of the `fn` module's globals and can be seen by the functions in it.

Comment: My issue is that I have to import functions from several different modules, so having to deal with this will crop up in some way or another

Comment: Then change your design so you don't have to do that.